# Create activated user in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-admin-client

I am using Keycloak 21.0.0 and Quarkus 2.16.3.Final.

I would like to create an active user in Keycloak from my programme.

The user is also created, but deactivated.
All other values were also transferred

Code:

```
UserResource userResource = usersRessource.get(user.getId());
kcUser.setUsername("user_test");
kcUser.setFirstName("user_test");
kcUser.setLastName("user_test");
kcUser.setEmail("user@test.com");
kcUser.setEnabled(true);
kcUser.setEmailVerified(true);

usersRessource.get(user.getId()).update(kcUser);
```

Keycloak Users:

[image]

Comment: `kcUser.setEnabled(user.getIsActive());` what value is `getIsActive()`?

Comment: it is boolean: true